# How to tag a photo to be used as a thumbnail when a page is linked to on Facebook

Tags: facebook, semantic-web, semantic-markup

When a person posts a link on Facebook, Facebook automatically finds a photo to be used as a thumbnail that shows up in the news feed. Is there some sort of (HTML) markup to surround a photo you'd like to use as the first choice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you want are the `<meta>` tags that Facebook defines in their documentation on [Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/external/open_graph/).

You don't put the metadata around the image itself, rather, you put it in the head of the document, like this:

```html
<meta name="title" content="The Title Of The Link" />
<meta name="description" content="A description of the link would go here." /> 
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.example.com/images/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: If I want to share links dynamically (from database) how can I specify each one in head.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is now out of date. The new way to do it is with an [open graph tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/checklist/) e.g.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/picture.jpg" />
```

Comment: I used this meta property today and works fine. Some more details including the preview details is available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817334/281087

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that if everything doesn't work, than, may be, you should reload Facebook cache.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/