# Facebook like button ,image is not posted

Tags: php, facebook

I implemented the Facebook like button in our website,but when the like button is clicked, content posted to the wall,but the image in the page is not posted to the wall and also the title.I tried using the Open Graph Protocol too.But it is still not posting the image.Where am I going wrong? I would like to implement the like button as it is here http://www.bjsbrewhouse.com/menus/shareable-appetizers

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Text-General" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://website.com/img/general.jpg" />
```

Comment: Can edit in the code you used to add open graph to your pages?  "or a link to your pages if it is added"

Comment: good and working solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that Facebook has cached your page's Open Graph data before you updated the OG tags to display the image. Use Facebook's Debug/Lint tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Change the URL that you submit to the linter with a query parameter (e.g. http://yourdomain.com/path/to/like/page?=v2) and it will treat is as a new URL and display the most current Open Graph data from your page.

If that doesn't work, repost with the OG tags you have on the page and I'd be happy to take a look!

Comment: when I use the lint tool,I am  able to see my og:image and og:title that I have supplied,but I am not able to see that in the facebook wall

Comment: Good, you're doing everything correctly. Facebook simply has cached that URL from its first "Liked" instance and will typically re-index that page **each 24-hrs**. If it is imperative that the Like button displays all the information you want immediately, you might need to change the name of the file on your site. If that is not possible, continue trying to use the lint tool with the original (current) URL and Facebook may attempt to re cache your page with the updated (working) OG tags.