# Facebook share link without JavaScript

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

The following link is for sharing a page on Twitter:

http://twitter.com/share

Is there a similar option for Facebook that doesn't require JavaScript?

I know about http://facebook.com/sharer.php, but that requires a get parameter to be inserted manually (which I'm not going to do), or with JavaScript (which doesn't fit my situation).

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You could use

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#url" target="_blank">
    Share
</a>
```

Currently there is no sharing option without passing current url as a parameter. You can use an indirect way to achieve this.

1. Create a server side page for example: "/sharer.aspx"
2. Link this page whenever you want the share functionality.
3. In the "sharer.aspx" get the refering url, and redirect user to "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={referer}"

Example ASP .Net code:

```cs
public partial class Sharer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var referer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
        {
            // some error logic
            return;
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referer));
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this is a nice option. But If I want this to open in a pop up like the js version , What should I do ?
At this moment it is opening in a new tab ! 
Thanks !

Comment: This is not what I was asking for. This requires you to know the URL of the page being shared, so you can replace "#url" in your `href` with the page's URL. Using the http://twitter.com/share link, however doesn't require you to insert the URL of the page your sharing.

Comment: Do you know how to send an image?

Comment: @miguelmpn (and the newer reader), see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4758285/863110). In short: [`og:image`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share) tag.

Comment: Is there documentation for this particular method?

Comment: Here is a giant list of URL's to social networks for sharing, to help: https://properprogramming.com/blog/45-custom-social-network-urls-for-sharing-content/

Answer (score 153):

***Ps 2: As pointed out by [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272647/justin-skiles), check out [Facebook's new Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog). Will leave the answer as is for posterity. This answer is obsolete***

---

Short answer, yes there's a similar option for Facebook, that doesn't require javascript (well, there's some minimal inline JS that is not compulsory, see note).

*Ps: The `onclick` part only helps you customise the popup a little bit but is **not required** for the code to work ... it will work just fine without it.*

**Facebook**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL&t=TITLE"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;"
   target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">
</a>
```

**Twitter**

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=URLENCODED_URL&via=TWITTER_HANDLE&text=TEXT"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;"
   target="_blank" title="Share on Twitter">
</a>
```

Comment: @superluminary ... it has but doesn't require it. I had mentioned that you can remove it (the onclick part) ... and it will still work. But I can see how it all not 100% clear ... I'll edit it.

Comment: Nice example of graceful degradation!

Comment: +1. Should change `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php` to `http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php`

Comment: I would update this answer to point people to use the [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) as directed by Facebook.

Comment: What is `TWITTER_HANDLE` parameter?

Comment: @HamidFzM That's just a placeholder for your Twitter handle. Replace appropriately. Unless your Twitter handle is actually "TWITTER_HANDLE".

Comment: onclick opening a pop not a new window. is there any way i can redirect it to a new window?

Answer (score 45):

It is possible to include JavaScript in your code and still support non-JavaScript users.

If a user clicks any of the following links without JavaScript enabled, it will simply open a new tab:

```
<!-- Remember to change URL_HERE, TITLE_HERE and TWITTER_HANDLE_HERE -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL_HERE&t=TITLE_HERE" target="_blank" class="share-popup">Share on Facebook</a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URL_HERE&via=TWITTER_HANDLE_HERE&text=TITLE_HERE" target="_blank" class="share-popup">Share on Twitter</a>
<a href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=URL_HERE" target="_blank" class="share-popup">Share on Googleplus</a>
```

Because they contain the `share-popup` class, we can easily reference these in jQuery, and change the window size to suit the domain we are sharing from:

```
$(".share-popup").click(function(){
    var window_size = "width=585,height=511";
    var url = this.href;
    var domain = url.split("/")[2];
    switch(domain) {
        case "www.facebook.com":
            window_size = "width=585,height=368";
            break;
        case "www.twitter.com":
            window_size = "width=585,height=261";
            break;
        case "plus.google.com":
            window_size = "width=517,height=511";
            break;
    }
    window.open(url, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,' + window_size);
    return false;
});
```

No more ugly inline JavaScript, or countless window sizing alterations. And it still supports non-JavaScript users.

Comment: Nice solution! Also, I'm using some javascript to fill in the current page URL: `$(".share-popup").each(function(){
  var href = $( this ).attr( "href" );
  href = href.replace( "URL_HERE", document.URL );
  $( this ).attr( "href", href );
 });`

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni it's better to include the current URL server-side to support non-JavaScript users

Answer (score 35):

Try these link types actually works for me.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=YOUR_URL_HERE
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=YOUR_URL_HERE
https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOUR_URL_HERE
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=YOUR_URL_HERE
```

Answer (score 11):

I know it's an old thread, but I had to do something like that for a project and I wanted to share the 2019 solution.

The new `dialog` API can get params and be used without any javascript.

The params are:

- `app_id` (Required)
- `href` The URL of the page you wish to share, in case none has passed will use the current URL.
- `hashtag` have to have the `#` symbol for example #amsterdam
- `quote` text to be shared with the link

You can create an href without any javascript what so ever.

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?&app_id=APP_ID&link=URI&display=popup&quote=TEXT&hashtag=#HASHTAG" target="_blank">Share</a>
```

One thing to consider is that Facebook is using [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) so in case your OG tags are not set properly you might not get the results you wish for.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. However, I get the error `Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.` I am on localhost. Any ideas? I have tried to include several domains in both the `Basic` and `Advanced` settings on FB but no luck.

Comment: Does not look like `display=popup` is working on desktop.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Feed URL "Direct URL" option, as described on the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) page:

> You can also bring up a Feed Dialog by explicitly directing the user to the /dialog/feed endpoint:

```
  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?  
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response`
```

Looks like they no longer mention "sharing" anywhere in their docs; this has been replaced with the concept of adding to your Feed.

Comment: But it is not possible to access that dialog without registering an App ID?

Answer (score 7):

Lots of these answers no longer apply, so here's mine:

Use the Share Dialog described at the [Facebook Dev Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

Example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=<your_app_id>
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

But you have to put in your registered app_id, the href, and a redirect uri.

Comment: So this is only useful if you're a registered in the Facebook dev program?

Answer (score 3):

http://facebook.com/sharer.php is deprecated

You have a few options (use the iframe version):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. I just want to use an anchor element.

Comment: Sorry, then you're out of luck.  It's either Javascript or iFramed.

Comment: So are you saying you are unable to implement the iFramed?  What does your code look like?  Can you post a link to a sample of the iframed version that is not working for you?

Comment: I'm saying that if the user has JavaScript disabled, then they won't be able to share the page on Facebook. I was just wondering if there was a similar link like http://twitter.com/share but for facebook.

Comment: How do you know `sharer.php` is deprecated?

Comment: @Flimm Please see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252983554810810/ and read the comment from Noorin. {quote}Noorin Ladhani ·  · Facebook Team
Hi Ronald - The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button. {quote}

Comment: today it shows: There is something wrong with the configurator

Answer (score 2):

For those that wish to use javascript but do not want to use the Facebook javascript library:

```
<a id="shareFB" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL&t=TITLE"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;"   target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">Share on Facebook</a>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("shareFB").setAttribute("href", "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + document.URL);</script>
```

Works even if javascript is disabled, but gives you a popup window with share preview if javascript is enabled.

Saves one needles click while not using any Facebook js spyware :)

Comment: Is there any way to open it in new tab. Right now its pening a popup

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @rybo111's solution, here's what a LinkedIn share would be:

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={articleUrl}&title={articleTitle}&summary={articleSummary}&source={articleSource}" target="_blank" class="share-popup">Share on LinkedIn</a>
```

and add this to your Javascript:

```
case "www.linkedin.com":
    window_size = "width=570,height=494";
    break;
```

As per the LinkedIn documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin (See "Customized Url" section)

For anyone who's interested, I used this in a Rails app with a LinkedIn logo, so here's my code if it might help:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('linkedin.png', size: "50x50"), "http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=#{job_url(@job)}&title=#{full_title(@job.title).html_safe}&summary=#{strip_tags(@job.description)}&source=SOURCE_URL", class: "share-popup" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

How to share content: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

You have to choose use the deprecated function without JS, and check every day, or follow the way use JS and have fun.