# Facebook Sharer link not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, share-button

I have created a button in my website that will share the page. But on clicking the link Facebook is showing "file not found". Facebook debugger in showing no problem

URL i want to shar: http://www.huzup.com/subcategory.php?subcategory=Mollywood&highlight=www.mohanlal.com

Link on the button to share: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.huzup.com/subcategory.php?subcategory=Mollywood&highlight=www.mohanlal.com

Comment: you could refer to this posts may help :




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-no-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.urlencode('http://www.huzup.com/subcategory.php?subcategory=Mollywood&highlight=www.mohanlal.com').'">share on Facebook</a>';
?>
```

Comment: urlencode replaces special characters in the url like :// and & etc to characters that the browser can understand. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php