# Facebook share link does not remember the URL to share

Tags: facebook, share

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-no-javascript) and its answers explain what a Facebook share links should look like:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#url
```

But when the user is not currently logged in to Facebook when he clicks this link, the `url` to share has been replaced by the URL of the FB login page:

[image]

Sorry, I don't know how to make FB show this in English, but you can see in the naviagtion bar that the value for `u` has been lost after login and now reads `...?u&ret=login` instead of `...?u#url&ret=login`.

You can try this yourself by logging out of Facebook and following this link: http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F29557906%2Ffacebook-share-link-does-not-remember-the-url-to-share

#### How can I force Facebook to "remember" which URL to share?

I would prefer to avoid using JavaScript (but will do, if necessary), and I don't want to register a Facebook app to use the [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when the user is not currently logged in to Facebook […]

It doesn’t work when they *are* logged in to Facebook either (then it just shows a field to input a URL to share first) – and that’s because you did not pass any value for the `u` parameter, but *ended* the query string after `?u=` by using the `#` sign, which of course starts the *hash* part of a URL, and that does not even get send to the server …

Remove the `#` – the *correct* link is http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F29557906%2Ffacebook-share-link-does-not-remember-the-url-to-share

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you want to share something on someone facebook wall without using any facebook api ?

For what i know you can't. The post you are referring to is 3 years old, and not accurate anymore.