# share some text on facebook on clicking the link

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to share some details on the users `facebook wall`. Actually i want to allow the users to share some details on his `facebook wall` when they click on the `facebook share link`.

I have currently read the documentation and SO's question only thing i got is `href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=#url`

reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-no-javascript) question

but this only supports the url . Actually i want to send some details like

`My Monthly Bill = $100 
My Tax is = $100`

How would i share the content or message on the wall?

Comment: please read the platform policy, prefilling is not allowed. you can only use open graph tags, read about those in the docs too. they should be static though, not dynamic.

Comment: @luschn i am putting this text statically. user will be able to click the link when it have some. Can you please explain further because i am new to these social networking sites integration.

Comment: You have to share a URL. Then you can put og:description on that URL that contains your text. That will show when the user share the URL. You can not share text directly

Comment: so if i want to share something like `Hi my name is test`. what should i do or the facebook did not provide that.