# Facebook share button not showing image etc from og tags on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I've got problem with Facebook social share button. After click on share button when popup shows up, it doesn't display image provided in og:image tag, and also title and description from og:title and og:description tag. This is problem with my project served on localhost:3000.

I've also tried to copy and paste code from facebook site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) and just run separate index.html in browser, but even that doesn't work as expected (only showing url of site)

So what's the problem even with official code and how can I fix it, so my images, description and title will show up in popup?

Here is the code from Facebook Doc

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Website Title</title>
    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
  <meta property="og:url"           content="https://google.pl" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="http://javascript.info/article/call-apply-decorators/decorator-makecaching-wrapper.png" />
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://google.pl" 
    data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is problem with my project served on localhost:3000

OG Tags cannot work on localhost, Facebook needs to be able to reach the URL. Put your project on a public webserver to test OG tags.

Answer (score 0):

1. **data-href** must be the same as **og:url**
2. from my experience i can tell that og:image should be **.jpg** otherwise it happens you get errors with images
3. as @luschn said, your image should be on the web of course and not localhost
4. i recently had a loooot of issues with fb share button so i prefer to use [fb share link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-no-javascript) and customize the element with some css to make it look like a button or whatever

Comment: also the facebook share link is way more faster than including the fb sdk in your project only for a share button