# how to create a Facebook share button with only a share link?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to create Twitter and Facebook share buttons. I only want create share links because I don't want to take the buttons they provide from their docs. For Twitter this was really easy because it only expects one url parameter

(I'm using VueJs so I can pass in variables)

```
<a :href="`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=${shareText}`">Share</a>
```

where the `shareText` is just a property combining the page title and page url `${this.title} ${encodeURI(window.location.href)}`. From the Facebook docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ I was not able to find information about how to create a share link without downloading Facebook packages.

How can I create the equivalent for Facebook?

---

**Update**

From the comments I took this link [Facebook share link without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-without-javascript) for more information. I think there is no way I can share a text with a link so I try to stick with the link only. This is what I have so far

```
<a :href="`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${encodeURI(window.location.href)}`">Share</a>
```

In my application the generated sample link would look like

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://localhost:8080/users/1

When clicking on it the Facebook page opens up and shows this error message

[image]

So how can I fix it?

Comment: You want to share text or a link?

Comment: the link is more important but the best would be both, so just pass in a string, whatever it holds

Comment: Sharing a link is explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120539/facebook-share-link-without-javascript

Comment: thanks, so `:href="`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${window.location.href}`"` will do the trick I think

Comment: I would suggest just trying it

Comment: unfortunately it didn't. I updated my question

Comment: You can't share localhost. Specify a real URL.