# Facebook - no thumbnail despite trying all the solutions

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I have never had a problem getting Facebook to show thumbnails for shared links before, but for a site I've just launched, xmlplayground.com, it just refuses.

Weirdest of all, the Facebook Lint utility says my page is fine, and shows me the image!

I've tried lots from suggestions in various posts:

- adding the og:image meta tag
- adding the older rel="image_src" link tag
- declaring the og namespace in my html tag
- ensuring the path to the image is clean and friendly
- not using PNGs

I wondered whether it was because the image is not actually present in the page in an IMG tag, but even when I add it, no joy.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook

Comment: No dice. I did eventually fix it, though - I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this took an age to figure out. I followed all the rules, and the Facebook Linter said everything was fine. It even showed me my picture!

Eventually I read that the picture has to be at least 200px in both dimensions.

This is bizarre because I frequently share links from other sites of mine where the pictures are smaller than that, and they nonetheless show up.

In any case, if anyone's having trouble getting their pic onto Facebook links, check the dimensions.