# How to specify a thumbnail when sharing to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I ave embedded youtube video on my CodeIgniter page, i'm using official youtube embedding code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/msHFJhMqaKI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

But when I try to share my page into facebook, i have no thumbnail, is there a tag or something what can help me with sign my video as future facebook thumbnail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show particular image as thumbnail while implementing share on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook).  It doesn't matter exactly what you are sharing or how - the way to handle Facebook's previews of your site are in that post...

Comment: I can only specify image, not video? (btw. saw this post before)

Comment: If you want to have the video actually **play** within facebook you'll have to develop your own FLV player - that is a different story.  If all you want is a thumbnail image, then the `og:image` meta tag is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yap you should add the meta tags in your head portion

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://siim.lepisk.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/siim-blog-fb.png" />
```

after adding meta tag you can check what facebook scrap from your page

[facebook linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

here is some other meta tags that will be helpfull

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

**For more information**
[visit this link](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) ..

Comment: @Fuser97381 I always :)