# I want to create post with web site preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, preview

I want to create a post with web site preview. It must be similar as on screenshot.

[image]

How do I create a post with web preview? I want to add it on pages.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Post with web preview",  @"message", nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", myself.pageID]
                                     parameters:dict HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: Darn... I could have collected this bounty :/ But I don't want to repost the same answer on two different questions...

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8887746/558021) should give you the information you need. Basically, you'll have to implement some `og:meta` tags on the URL that you are sharing... That is how Facebook extracts the preview for share stories...

Comment: Is not my answer what you looked for?

Comment: @Chococroc, I didn't found any web preview in your code.

Comment: Are you asking a CSS question? I mean, what you want is seeing your html formatted like it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I want to create post and share it through graph-api.

Answer (score 2):

More info about posting links (what you call "post with web site preview") here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

I asumme you have your Facebook APP with your permissions set, and that you're using PHP-sdk classes. Anyway, the proccess is the same for any language, just changing the way you write it. Also, you need the user Access Token with the proper permission set.

Using the PHP-sdk from Facebook, process would be:

```
// Load FB class, and init it
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

// You set the User Access Token (you need to have it previously to this: Because you 
// requested before, or because you obtain it from Facebook)
$facebook->setAccessToken( $user_access_token );

try {
  // Set the link params:      
  if ( isset($config['link']) ) { 
     $args = array(
       'link'        => $link_url          //Url to be linked
     , 'name'        => $link_titulo       //Box title
     , 'description' => $link_descripcion  //Box Description
     , 'picture'     => $link_foto         //Photo to be posted
     , 'message'     => $link_message      //Message over the "link box"
     );

     // Post in the User/FB_Page wall
     $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $args);
  }
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     $fbError = $e->getResult();

  $result = array(
    'tipo'   => 'error'
  , 'code'   => $fbError['error']['code']
  , 'text'   => $fbError['error']['message']
  );

  print_r($result);
}
```

### Update

After reading your answer to my comment, I think you're looking just for the CSS and the layout. You can find something to achive the post formatting here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5NYD5/3/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using multiple ways,

If you are using facebook API then its easy, just like on FB(image will be automatically fetched)

```
Dim fb As FacebookClient = New FacebookClient('access_token')

Dim args As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()

args("message") = "Your Message to be posted"
args("link") = "http://www.example.com"

fb.Post("/me/feed", args)
```

I hope this will do,

else if you are not using FB API then its comparatively long way to grab image or create snapshot, of site manually. Just like search engine crawlers crawl after entering website. Its long way but yes possible.