# Force facebook to show my prefered images of the site in status link update

Tags: php, javascript, html, facebook

[image: facebook Example:]

Is there any way to control of the **thumbnail of facebook status** update when someone post a link of my website to their **FB status?** If yes, then can i make it dynamic depending on the link they share?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show particular image as thumbnail while implementing share on Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook) - please do some research before asking about a topic that has been broadly covered already again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and it is very easy, on each page simply add the meta tag "og:image" and set the path of your image, "og" stands for [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/). [Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

You can also find help on this [blog](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags) and display a custom title, description, ...

You may also be interested that there is also specific meta tags for links published in Twitter. [Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards).

For your information Facebook cache all the images, so if you change an existing image you may not directly see the new picture

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added "og:image" meta tag but not getting the image in update. Is there any way to remove the cache of FB?

Comment: Look at this link: [How to clear Facebook Share’s Cache](http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/)

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing the image url pass the dynamic url so that when you alick on any post or page  to share  on facebook that will share the image of that page not the staic image you entered