# Show particular thumbnail on Facebook when sharing TUMBLR link

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, tumblr

I read thru this post ([How to show particular image as thumbnail while implementing share on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689295/how-to-show-particular-image-as-thumbnail-while-implementing-share-on-facebook)) but, I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do this with a Tumblr link and no server space to use. My "og:image" (the main logo) is not 200x200 when Tumblr automatically resizes it to fit and I can't upload an image with a specific filename to Tumblr or tinypic, etc. as far as I know...

Any suggestions for some sort of "hack" for this? Thanks!

Oh and, here's my blog and the image I'd like to use...

http://wckdwrld.tumblr.com

http://24.media.tumblr.com/fe2f85fd86f428568ceb79c0f90921f6/tumblr_mw0zg2eqXq1skzrtzo1_1280.png

(the image uploaded to tumblr as a private post... I've done stuff like this successfully before for things like the background image, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Awesome Blog" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://myawesomeblog.tumblr.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/myawesomeimage.png" />
```

between in `<head>` tags to Your HTML structure in [Customize Blog](http://www.tumblr.com/customize/)

*(According to Tumblr, You have to define the* `og:url` *and* `og:title` *tags in your theme's HTML to overwrite the [OG meta tags](http://ogp.me))*

Here's an [example to share](http://xn--fj8h.tumblr.com/) (check its source)

Comment: It actually worked when I didn't define the og:url and og:title! Just inserted the meta tag with og:image between title and description tags.